# Removing columns, taking rowspan into account

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have the following example setup

http://jsfiddle.net/gibble/srBeB/

What I am trying to do, is remove the first two columns of a table

The issue is that the first column, contains cells that have a `rowspan='2'`

So when I remove it, then go to the next row, it removes a cell it shouldn't

Thoughts on how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since row spans are involved, you'll have to change your strategy. Your table has four columns, so instead of *removing the first two columns*, you should aim to *keep only the last two*.

You can achieve that easily by passing a negative upper bound to [slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/):

```
$(this).children("td, th").slice(0, -2).remove();
```

You will find an updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/srBeB/7/).